# Session[counter].open(options) does not work. Is there a workaround?

Tags: c#, session

I really need to have a Sessionarray that i can open with my options. I tried this code but all it does is throw a nullreferenceexception. I found out that this exception is only thrown when i use a session array.

```
 Session[] sessions = new Session[(int)counter];

  sessions[(int)counter].Open(options);
```

Midway I thought, maybe there was no Session at the index existing so i did this

```
Session[] sessions = new Session[(int)counter];
 Session session1 = new Session();   
sessions[(int)counter]= session1;
      sessions[(int)counter].Open(options);
```

it still didn't work.

What can i do to make this work. Please Help. I don't understand the concept of Session["something"] since it doesn't really work when creating a Session[]

Answer (score 0):

what kind of project? which Session-class?
I guess you will not need an Session-array.